# Store user preferences in a HTML5 WebWorks app

Tags: html, local-storage, blackberry-webworks, user-preferences

I'm developing a HTML5 Webworks application for Blackberry OS 5+.

I have to store user name, password and locale. However, I don't know how.

I could use local store, but it is only available on Blackberry OS 6+.

Someone suggested me that I can write my own plugin, but I don't know how to do it.

How can I store user name, password and language on Blackberry OS 5+?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.io.file.html

Use that link and maybe save to a file and read from a file? Its a shame you cant use local storage it would work great. What OS is it your using?

Thought this might be handy for you to read: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Using-localStorage-for-pre-OS-6-devices/td-p/703827

I've used it a few times and seems to work...

Comment: I want to develop it to Blackberry OS 5 or greater.